# PHP: strlen help. I need to display only 100 characters of a string then a hyperlink

Tags: php, database

OK so I have an Item description being echoed out from a database,

What I want to do is say:

if the description is over 100 characters display the 100 then display a hyper-link to read more about it.

else display the description.

I have already used strlen to get the length of the string but how do I tell it to only display that 100 then the hyperlink? HELP :( :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [limit text length in php and provide 'Read more' link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258557/limit-text-length-in-php-and-provide-read-more-link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
if(strlen($string) > 100) {
    echo substr($string, 0, 100).' '.$hyperlink;
}
else {
    echo $string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the function [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php), and possibly [wordwrap](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php).

If you can live with an additional database access you can simply store the `row id` (embed it in the hyperlink as a GET parameter etc.) and pass it as a parameter to the page showing full messages.

Answer (score 0):

Use substr():

```
if (strlen($str) > 100) {
  $str = substr($str,0,100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How's this?

```
if (strlen($theString) > 100)
{
  echo (substr($theString, 0, 100));
  writeHyperLink($theString);
}
else
{
   echo $theString;
}
```