# limit data character post

Tags: php, mysql

I want to limit the data to only 300 characters to be posted on the page. how i can i place a script under "description"?

Thanks

```
<?php $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM headlines ORDER BY serial DESC LIMIT 3"); while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  { ?>


<img src="./img/<?php echo $row['picture']?>" height="284px" width="465px" /><br />
<div id="headlinetitle"><a href="./headlines.php?code=<?php echo $row['serial'];?>|productname=<?php echo $row['title']; ?>"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></a></div>

<?php echo $row['description']; ?>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258557/limit-text-length-in-php-and-provide-read-more-link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `substring` like

```
echo substr($row['description'], 0, 300);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [substr()](https://www.php.net/substr) and replace

```
echo $row['description']
```

with

```
echo substr($row['description'], 0, 300);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use:

```
if ( !empty($row['description']) ) {
    $description = ( strlen($row['description']) > 300 ? substr($row['description'], 0, 300) . '...' : $row['description'] );
}
```

The code above will fill `$description` with either the full description text if its < 300 characters. If it's longer then 300 characters, it will cut off the description text on 300 characters and append '...' to indicate the shortening of the string.