# php limiting search results in text

Tags: php, html, regex

After some search and googling I found code for highlighting and limiting the search results within a text similar to this one:

```
$text = preg_replace("/^.*?(.{0,100})\b($word)\b(.{0,100}).*?$/mi", '\1<span class="highlight_word">\2</span>\3', $text);
```

Unfortunately I always get the complete `$text` back even though the contents of `$word` is placed within the span as intended.

My question is now how I may reduce the contents of `$text` to just show 100 characters before and after the search result (contents of $word). 
I also checked the regular expression in several variants using a webportal and got the desired result. Nevertheless my php code is not showing what is intended.
Any help is really appreciated as I assume there is a very stupid error on my side.

Comment: How's this related to mysql? What is `$text`? What is intended and what is displayed?

Comment: After your preg_replace, get the position of $word, then use substr to get the 100 before and 100 after. IOW, if $p1 = the position of $word in $text,  $rslt = substr($text,$p1 - 100, 200 + strlen($word)) or similar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [limit text length in php and provide 'Read more' link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258557/limit-text-length-in-php-and-provide-read-more-link)

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `m` flag, `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of lines, not the beginning and end of the string. So this only matches and replaces in a single line of `$text` at a time, and non-matching lines are left alone.

If you want to match across multiple lines, use the `s` modifier. That permits `.` to match newlines, but `^` and `$` still match only the beginning and end of `$text`.