# How to add read more link to display its content on a modal box

Tags: php, mysql

I just edited this question after i have reviewed the possible duplicate here [limit text length in php and provide 'Read more' link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258557/limit-text-length-in-php-and-provide-read-more-link)
But it still doesn't point to what i want so i decided to drop an image of my table for better understanding.
[image: html result table]
In this table are posts that are displayed from mysql database. Now i don't want the posts to be fully displayed just yet until i click on one. Only then should it show the full post "IN A MODAL BOX POPUP".

Here are my files:

home.php

```
<?php
include 'config/server.php';

    // if session is not set this will redirect to login page
    if( !isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit;
    }
    // select loggedin users detail
  $res=mysqli_query($dbconn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=".$_SESSION['user']);
    $userRow=mysqli_fetch_array($res);

  // fetch the records to be updated
  if (isset($_GET['update'])) {
    $id = $_GET['update'];
    $edit_state = true;
    $rec = mysqli_query($dbconn, "SELECT * FROM diary_table WHERE id=$id");
    $records = mysqli_fetch_array($rec);
    $note = $records['note'];
    $id = $records['id'];
  }

?>

                <div class="table-responsive">  
                <table class="table table-bordered">  
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Note</th>
        <th>created</th>
        <th>Updated</th>
        <th colspan="2">Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['note']; ?><a href="#view" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data">View</a></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['created_at']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['updated_at']; ?></td>
          <td>
          <a style="text-decoration: none; padding: 2px 5px; background: #2E8B57; color: #FFFFFF;  border-radius: 3px;" href="home.php?update=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Update</a>
          </td>
        <td>
          <a style="text-decoration: none; padding: 2px 5px; color: #FFFFFF; border-radius: 3px; background: #800000;" href="config/server.php?del=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Delete</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
      </div>
  </div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="view" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4>Full Note</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-10">
<textarea disabled>
              <?php echo $id; ?>
              <?php echo $note; ?>
  `</textarea>`          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close it</a>
            </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the server.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    // initialize variables
        // $note = "";
        // $id = 0;
        // $edit_state = false;

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    // connect to database
    require_once 'database.php';

        if( !isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit;
    }

    // if save button is clicked
    if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
        $note = addslashes($_POST['note']);
        $created_at = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $user_id = trim($_SESSION['user']);

    // basic post validation
    if (empty($note)) {
        $error = true;
        $noteError = "Field cannot be empty.";
    }else {
        // insert records if no error
        echo 
        $query = "INSERT INTO diary_table (note, user_id, created_at) VALUES ('$note', ' ".$user_id." ' , '$created_at'";
        mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);
        header('location: ../home.php'); // redirect to home page after inserting
    }
}
    // update records
    if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
        $note = $_POST['note'];
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "Note updated";
        mysqli_query($dbconn, "UPDATE diary_table SET note='$note', updated_at=NOW() WHERE id=$id");
        header('location: ../home.php');
    }

    // delete records
    if (isset($_GET['del'])) {
        $id = $_GET['del'];
        mysqli_query($dbconn, "DELETE FROM diary_table WHERE id=$id");
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "Shipment deleted";
        header('location: ../home.php');
    }
    // retrieve records
    $results = mysqli_query($dbconn, "SELECT * FROM diary_table WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
?>
```

Comment: All information is provided Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258557/limit-text-length-in-php-and-provide-read-more-link

Comment: Please use prepared statements with placeholders for security reasons.

Comment: Can I get a sample or a link to what you mean pls?